# Как удалить весь ввод после команды read в Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

При заполнении прогресс бара зажатием кнопки F (или любой другой буквой) в инпут консоли записываются невидимые буквы.
Проблема в том, что при запуске select принимает невидимые символы как нужный ввод значения и пишет ошибку из кейса **invalid option ffffffffffffffff1**.
Следующий же ввод проходит нормально.
При использовании кнопки "Space" для заполнения прогресс бара, такой ошибки нету.
Как удалить весь ввод после окончания цикла? Чтобы следующий select был с пустым вводом

```
#!/bin/bash
progress_bar(){

stty -echo  #hide input 
PROGRESS=0
bar=''
key_1="f"   #Eng
key_2="а"   #Rus

while true;
do
read -rs -N 1 -t 1 input
    if [[ "$input" = "$key_1" || "$input" = "$key_2" ]]; then 
        ((PROGRESS+=1))
        sleep 0.05
        bar="${bar} "
        echo -ne "\r"
        echo -ne "\e[46m$bar\e[0m"
        echo -n "${PROGRESS}%"
    else
        ((PROGRESS-=1))
        sleep 0.05
        bar="${bar} "
        echo -ne "\r"
        echo -ne "\e[41m$bar\e[0m"
        echo -n "${PROGRESS}%"
    fi

    if [ $PROGRESS = 100 ];then
        echo ""
        echo "progress 100%"
        sleep 3s
        echo -e result
        break;
    fi
    
    if [ $PROGRESS = -10 ];then
        echo -e skip_progress
        break;
    fi
done
}

quit_menu(){
stty echo
clear

echo -e 'Please select \e[44m"Restart"\e[0m or \e[46m"Quit of game\e[0m"'
select opt in 'Restart' 'Quit'; 
do
     case $opt in
       "Restart")
            echo "you chose restart" 
            sleep 1s
            echo game
            ;;
        "Quit")
            clear
            echo "Exit..."
            exit 0 
            ;;
        *)
            echo "invalid option $REPLY"
            ;;
    esac
done
sleep 5s
}

echo -e "Hold down the key 'F'"
progress_bar
quit_menu
```

Comment: Вариант с dev/null не работает
`read -rs -n1 -t input 1>& /dev/null `
Cоздавать пустую переменную `input=""` тоже не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Перевод клавиши "забой" на кнопу ввода.

```
read -rs -N 1 -t 1 input
stty erase "$key_1"
```

в дополнение к комментарию.
У тебя ошибка при использовании /dev/null
нужно было писать вот так

```
$input 1>& /dev/null
```